# How can I make an animation last "n" amount of seconds when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

I did this example to try to explain my problem.

[image]

I have an element of class .square and I want that when the trigger that is on the same `.square` is fired and the transition lasts `10` real seconds, that is, that the movement of the scroll down while it is on `.square`, lasts 10 seconds until come out of it.

```
    squareScroll.to(".square", 10,{autoAlpha:1})
```

currently my problem is that it does not take 10 real seconds. in other words I need the transition from start to finish to last 10 real seconds.

How can I do it?

this is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XoSHncr8lKhNSYs2?open=lib%2Fscript.js

```
   <div style="height:700px"></div>
   <div class="square"></div>
   <div style="height:1000px"></div>


    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

    var squareScroll= new TimelineMax();

    squareScroll.to(".square", 10,{autoAlpha:1})


    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: ".square",
        triggerHook:0.8,
        duration: "100%"
        })
        .setTween(squareScroll)
        .addIndicators()
        .addTo(controller);
```

Comment: We at GreenSock don't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead we recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Comment: @ZachSaucier  thanks for answering,Do you have an example where the total animation of an object is controlled in real seconds when scrolling?

Comment: That concept doesn't make sense. Users scroll at different rates. Either the animation is controlled by the scroll position or it's not. Perhaps you just want the animating timing to be eased? If that's the case you can make use of ScrollTrigger's scrub property like `scrub: 1`.

Comment: @ZachSaucier can you help me please with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65068807/how-can-i-make-each-item-last-longer-until-its-transition-is-complete