# how can i make each item last longer until its transition is complete?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have this code with which I hope to make myself understood.

```
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
  ScrollTrigger.defaults({
    toggleActions: "restart pause resume none",
    // markers: true,
  });
  let square = gsap.timeline({
    scrollTrigger: {
      start: "top center",
      end: "200px 100px",
      toggleActions: "restart none reverse none",
      //markers: true,
      scrub: true,
      trigger: ".square1",
      toggleActions: "restart none reverse none",
    },
  });


  square.from(".square1", {
    autoAlpha: 0,
    duration: 3,
  });
  square.from(
    ".square2",
    {
      autoAlpha: 0,
      duration: 3,
      x: "-50%"
    },
    "-=3"
  );

let circle=gsap.timeline({
    scrollTrigger: {
      start: "top center",
      end: "200px 100px",
      toggleActions: "restart none reverse none",
      //markers: true,
      scrub: true,
      trigger: ".circle",
      toggleActions: "restart none reverse none",
    },
  });


 circle.from(".circle", {
    autoAlpha: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    rotate:30
  });
```

In my real code, I plan to include audios for each `animation`. For example, the first audio can last `30 seconds`, so I would like the `first animation` to `last 30 seconds` and when it ends, the next one begins, which will have the same scenario, for example, audio 2 has `20 seconds` so I will need my `second animation` to last a total of `20 seconds`.

[image]

I'm using the `duration` property, but I'm not achieving my goal, I don't know how to delay the next animation or make an animation last longer.

**Note**: eventually I will do something to make the `scroll` move automatically, but eventually the user will be able to move the `scroll` and from the point where the `scroll` stops my animation will continue.
and this offset will be a transition of `scroll` from position `y = 0` to the end in a total number of seconds according to the number of total audios.
I hope to make me understand

With this example I would like to simulate that the `first animation` takes a long time and when it finishes continue the next one and so on.

I hope to make me understand

how can I do it?

this is my live code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PvHLb9b0HHcdX3Er?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: This question was answered [on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/26367-how-can-i-make-each-item-last-longer-until-its-transition-is-complete/).